# How to get only formula from row in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data frame
How can i copy the Previous Record and Paste as Last Record, clear Values ONLY and then add to same data frame.

```
 Record  Data Cust_Name   Position  Val  Formula                        id

0      41    30      John  Developer   41     21.0  =CONCATENATE(B2, "-",D2)

1      51    40       Tom  Developer   51     40.0  =CONCATENATE(B3, "-",D3)

2      32    21     Bruce     Tester   11      NaN  =CONCATENATE(B4, "-",D4)

3      71    60   Mamooty  Developer   51      NaN  =CONCATENATE(B5, "-",D5)
```

Comment: What's your expected output, and show your input. not clear to me what you're after.

Comment: I think you want join 2 columns together, check answers in dupe and if still problem add your code to question with expected output.

Comment: `df['first_column'].astype(str).add('-').add(df['second_column'].astype(str))` or `df['first_column'].astype(str).str.cat(df['second_column'].astype(str),sep = '-')`

Comment: @Datanovice Thanks in Advance, I am new to python development. I have obtained above DataFrame using pandas. I am able to write to excel using data frame, but the formulas that I have added is only applicable to the above mention rows. How to add a new record when this is the last record? This is a problem, because in Excel if you add a new last record, the Formulas are not copied. So,  in this scenario, can i copy the Previous Record and Paste as Last Record, clear Values ONLY and then use this record to overwrite with the new values?

Comment: why not just concatenate it in Pandas? you can do as ansev has said? if you need more help re-formulate ur question with epxefed output

Comment: @ansev  How to add a new row in excel sheet with previous row formula and not values. I have an excel with rows contains both formula and values I need to get the formulas only. By using pandas or any other library.